# Animation is too fast

Tags: mathematics, animation

I have an animation of a bullet but it seems to be going much faster than i was expecting.

I currently set it to `0.5 pixels per second` yet it seems to be moving way over hundreads of pixels per second.

Not quite sure where my logic is going wrong:

This is inside my gameLoop which im using to calculate it:

```
var deltaTime = (new Date().getTime() - started) / 1000; // divide to get seconds    
var position = deltaTime * bulletVelocity; //bulletVelocity is 0.5

var vectorX = destinationX - startX;
var vectorY = destinationY - startY;
var distance = Math.sqrt(vectorX * vectorX + vectorY * vectorY);

var x = startX + (vectorX * position);
var y = startY + (vectorY * position);

if (x < destinationX && y < destinationY) {
    ctx2.drawImage(pulse, x, y); //draw the sprite on canvas
}
```

Have i got my logic wrong here i cannot work out why its moving so fast.

Comment: You multiply the speed by the total distance to travel.  That does not immediately make sense to me.  You should comment your own code to explain what it is doing.  The problem might become apparent if you try to express it explicitly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging your code for you.

Comment: @SethBattin i multiply the timeElapsed which is `deltaTime` by velocity on line 2? Where am i multiplying distance by speed?

Comment: `var position = deltaTime * bulletVelocity;` and `var vectorX = destinationX - startX;` and then `var x = startX + (vectorX * position)`

Comment: @SethBattin so its the last two vars where my logic failed?

Comment: I can't answer that.  This is (one of the reasons) why code debug questions are considered off-topic here.  It's tough to tell you a correct answer because your intent isn't known.  But! Commenting your code would help with that problem, too.

Comment: Im not seeing whats difficult to follow the problem being about drawing the bullet's X:Y with a fixed velocity. from start to destination. Asking on SO wouldn't make sense not everyone deals with game animations

Comment: It seems you want to draw a bullet using an analytic solution instead of integrated? But its not quite doing either.

Comment: Its drawing it, just much faster than 0.5 pixels per second as i had planned. I don't know what analytic / integrated solutions mean =/

Comment: I was telling you to comment your code for your own benefit.  It has problems, so carefully writing down the process adjacent to the code might help you figure it out for yourself.  I can't tell you exactly what's wrong.  Would you like to move this discussion to a chat room?  [Like this one?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11871/seth-and-dave)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to divide 'vectorX' and 'vectorY' by 'distance'.

If you do that, the code should work.